# How to download a helm chart as a file for templating?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, harbor, helm3

I can successfully push a helm chart to my harbor registry:

```
helm registry login -u robot$myrobo -p ... https://myregistry.mycompany.com
helm chart save mychart.gz myregistry.mycompany.com/myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1 
helm chart push myregistry.mycompany.com/myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1
```

I can pull the chart as well:

```
helm registry login -u robot$myrobo -p ... https://myregistry.mycompany.com
helm chart pull myregistry.mycompany.com/myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1
```

Both commands succeed, but now I want to run

```
helm template name path/to/the/chart/I/just/downloaded -f another_file | further_processing
```

But `path/to/the/chart/I/just/downloaded` does not exist. It used to with helm 2 and another registry but now (with helm3) the file does not seem to be physically downloaded somewhere.

Except into the cache https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/#where-are-my-charts where I could probably parse the index.json and somehow get to my data but that is not desired. Is there a convenient way to access my files in the template command?

## Proceedings:

Answer by Rafał Leszko:

I tried:

```
$ helm pull myregistry.mycompany.com/myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1
Error: repo myregistry.mycompany.com not found
$ helm pull myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1
Error: repo myrepo not found
```

I know there are no typos because `helm chart pull myregistry.mycompany.com/myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1` succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this command:

```
helm pull hazelcast/hazelcast --untar --destination ./chart
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this command over the solutions proposed in the existing other answers? Why do you recommend this variant?  (Apart from the fact that you seem to have trouble with making it work... but you are not asking for help in an answer post, are you?)

Answer (score 0):

With Helm 3, you can use the `helm pull` command. It downloads the given helm chart to the current directory.

Try the following commands. There work fine.

```
helm pull hazelcast/hazelcast
helm template hazelcast hazelcast-*.tgz
```

Comment: That does not work for me. For `helm pull myrepo/mychart:0.0.0-1` I get `Error: repo myrepo not found`

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands below. You will need to add repository of Hazelcast before pulling the chart.

```
helm repo add hazelcast https://hazelcast-charts.s3.amazonaws.com/
helm repo update
helm pull hazelcast/hazelcast
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).